# Transaction Aborted in C# transaction scope

Tags: c#, asp.net, transactionscope

I saw so many example while googling regarding Transaction Scope.But i tried to do that,So in my case it throws the exception.Exception shows "Transaction Aborted".. I saw ther's may solution it shows Close the connection.but here i close it in finally block.Can anyone helpuot to solve this issue.

### UPDATED

Above connection issue solved.Now ti throws the exception in db.ExecuteNonQuery(cmd); section.Accroding to my knowledge until thrasaction has completed this doen't executed.

MyCode

```
  public bool NewsType(int Id)
    {

          bool status = false;
          DatabaseProviderFactory factory = new DatabaseProviderFactory();
          Database db = factory.Create("NewsCon");
          con.Open(); 

        using (TransactionScope transactionScope = new TransactionScope())
        {
            try
            {



                String query = @"DELETE FROM NewsType WHERE ID =: ID";
                cmd = db.GetSqlStringCommand(query);
                db.AddInParameter(cmd, "ID", DbType.Int32, Id);
                db.ExecuteNonQuery(cmd); //<-- Now it shows from the error here.But i think inside transaction scope this doesn't execute until transaction has completed.

                //Second step goes here

                status = true;

                transactionScope.Complete();
                transactionScope.Dispose();

            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                 throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }

            return status;
        }

    }
```

Comment: You don't seem to be using `con` anywhere. I would imagine your database factory is creating its own connection. Also, I would guess that you need to open a connection before starting a transaction.

Comment: @Rob please see edited post.

Comment: `Accroding to my knowledge until thrasaction has completed this doen't executed.` - This is wrong. The SQL will definitely execute immediately. The transaction just isn't committed, so changes will not be shown to other connections (depending on the scope).